Drilling 1” hole into apartment ceiling but keep hitting metal
I’m drilling around the electrical box in the ceiling where you would normally install a ceiling light because I need to anchor in an extra heavy light fixture. Unfortunately every hole I try to drill within a 5 inch radius of the box hits metal. I’m using an expensive drill bit that’s says it works for wood and metal but it does not go through the metal plate blocking the way. What’s an alternative way to do this?

Doesn't matter if its a rental or owned. Drilling into common property needs permission from condo board. There can be all kinds of things in there that can be damaged and can affect other owners - electrical, hvac, plumbing, and structural supports.

And ask for some plans

Use one of the electrical box fixing screws.

@DJ. So what other way can I anchor a 10lb light fixture
